# Can't execute an onLoad event

Tags: mootools

I have problems using an OnLoad event in a function:

```
        (function () {
            var ds = document.createElement('script');
            ds.type = 'text/javascript';
            ds.async = true;
            ds.src = 'http://' + ds_shortname + '.myscript.com/emb.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ds);
            ds.onLoad = function(){
                alert('ok');
                var ds_div = $('ds-div');
                if (IsConnected()) 
                {
                    alert('connect');
                }else{
                    alert('not connect');
                }
            }
        })();
```

In fact my `ds.onLoad` doesn't execute and I don't know why. I think it because my function execute herselve but I have no isea how to solve that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i think it should be onload (all lower) and not onLoad. see console for errors

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Utilities/Asset](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets) classes from More for this, for example like this:

```
new Asset.javascript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', { 
    onLoad:function(){
        $('message').set('text', 'Facebook loaded!'); 
    },
    async: true
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/FU5rk/

Directly related to your problem: you inject the element into the DOM before applying the onLoad event. I'm pretty sure that if the file is in cache, or a really fast download, it's simply loaded before you set the event handler.